# Display multiple rows values in a single row with multiple column

Tags: sql, pivot

```
   GR_NO| Month_ID | Amount
     43 |  7 | $200.00
     43 |  8 | $300.00
     43 |  9 | $500.00
```

show should be like this

```
GR_NO | 7       |       8 |    9 |
43    | $200.00 | $300.00 |$500.00
```

Comment: What have you tried and what output do you expect?

Comment: If you're only looking for `month_id`'s 7, 8, and 9 use a `case` statement. Otherwise look into using a pivot

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+pivot)

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/pivot.php  <<< That's for T-SQL, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually i am using sql

Comment: @Shawn can you please write a query of it ....

Comment: "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database"

Comment: @salmanhussain Which version of SQL are you using? There can be differences in the different flavors. If you follow the SQL Pivot link, it should give you enough background to learn how to pivot in whatever flavor of SQL you need.

Comment: @Shawn yah i am learning SQL pivot ... and thanks for your help buddy

Comment: Which version of SQL is this? Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT GR_NO, [7], [8], [9]
FROM
    (SELECT GR_NO, Month, Amount From Database.schema.TableName)
    AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    Sum(Amount)
FOR Month IN ( [7], [8], [9])
) AS PivotTable;
--<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

I researched this answer by looking at pivot table info here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Using MSSQL

Result

```
GR_NO   7         8         9
43      200.00    200.00    500.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what type of SQL you are using, this example is in MS T-SQL 2014 flavor. It should be similar in most other types of SQL.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e08e/2)

First, we set up the test table and data.

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( GR_NO int, Month_ID int, Amount decimal(10,2) ) ;
INSERT INTO t1 ( GR_NO, Month_ID, Amount )
VALUES 
    ( 43, 7, 200.00 )
  , ( 43, 8, 300.00 )
  , ( 43, 9, 500.00 )
  , ( 44, 2, 100.00 )
  , ( 43, 2, 250.00 )  /* Out of cycle */
  , ( 43, 4, 10.00 )  /* Aggregate 1 */
  , ( 43, 4, 10.00 )  /* Aggregate 2 */
;
```

**This is your Pivot Query**:

```
SELECT p.GR_NO
  , p.[1] AS Jan
  , p.[2] AS Feb
  , p.[3] AS Mar
  , p.[4] AS Apr /* Look at aggregated example. */
  , p.[5] AS May
  , p.[6] AS Jun
  , p.[7] AS Jul
  , p.[8] AS Aug
  , p.[9] AS Sep
  , p.[10] AS Oct
  , p.[11] AS Nov
  , p.[12] AS Dec 
  /* After the pivot, columns come from p. */
FROM (
  SELECT GR_NO, Month_ID, Amount
  FROM t1
  /* Source table for pivoting data. */
) s
PIVOT (
  SUM(Amount) /* Has to be an aggregate function. */
  FOR Month_ID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
  /* These are the fields you'd like to end up in the pivot. */
) p
```

Which gives us:

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e08e/2/0)**:

```
| GR_NO |    Jan | Feb |    Mar |    Apr |    May |    Jun |    Jul |    Aug |    Sep |    Oct |    Nov |    Dec |
|-------|--------|-----|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|    43 | (null) | 250 | (null) |     20 | (null) | (null) |    200 |    300 |    500 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|    44 | (null) | 100 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/pivot.php